# How can I use Proc SQL to find all the records that only exist in one table but not the other?

Tags: sql, sas

I'm trying to do this in Enterprise Guide, with a task, otherwise I would just use a data step.

In a data step, this would be:

```
data names;
 input name $;
 datalines;
  John
  Mary
  Sally
  Fred
  Paul
 ;
run;

data check;
 input name $;
 datalines;
  Mary
  Fred
 ;

Proc sort data=names; by name; run;
Proc sort data=check; by name; run;

Data work.not_in_check;
 merge names(in=n) check(in=c);
 by name;
 if n and not c;
run;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's one way. There are surely many others.

```
proc sql;
 create table not_in_check as
 select name
 from names
 where name not in (select name from check);
quit;
```

Answer (score 7):

Another slight variation is:

```
proc sql;
create table not_in_check as select 
 a.* from names as a left join 
          check as b on
          a.name=b.name
          where b.name is null;
quit;
```

Comment: This is the method I ended up using in EG. In the Filter Data section, I used b.name is missing. It would be great to see an explanation about why when I want a.name to not be present in b, b.name is null(missing) makes that happen....

Comment: It's because 2 columns are being read in, a.name and b.name.  These are then matched and therefore if a name exists in a but not b then the b.name record will be missing.  The left join with the is null where clause ensures you only keep the names in a but not b.  The select a.* ensures it only outputs data from table a, even though it is reading in data from both tables.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The following method is pretty simple way to get records present in one table and not in the other.

Created table new with records containing sex = M, the result after the query will be records with sex = F.

Example:

```
data new;
set sashelp.class;
where sex = 'M';
run;
proc sql;
create table new1 as
select * from sashelp.class
except all 
select * from new;
quit;
```

Will put the code to test on my actual datasets which are of around 100k obs and update the result.

P.S: I know the question has been asked answered and forgotten,I was looking for a way to do the above and couldn't find a direct answer any where. So, adding so that it may come handy. :)

My first answer also. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
proc sql;
 create table inNamesNotIncheck
 as
 select *
 from names n
 where not exists
 (select name
 from check c
 where n.name=c.name);
quit;
```

Comment: Hi, your post has been flagged as "low quality", probably because it consists solely of code. You could massively improve your answer by providing an explanation of exactly how and why this answers the question?

Comment: I appreciate the addition of the code.  It shows a different but viable approach to the already described problem.  Thank-you.